# ¿Cómo soluciono "Segmentation Fault"?

Tags: c++, hilos

Disculpen recientemente estoy estudiando como trabajar con programación con hilos en C++ y me dejaron este ejercicio.

> Realizar un programa con una variable entera global con un valor
> inicial de cero. Crear un hilo que incremente la variable global en A
> unidades. Crear otro hilo que la disminuya en B unidades. Al final el
> hilo principal(main) imprimirá el valor de la variable global.

Y conseguí este código, pero al ejecutarlo me marca **"Segmentation Fault"**, ¿Alguien me podría ayudar?, no se a que se refiere o que debo de hacer, gracias.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

int a=0,A=0,B=0;

void *suma(void *data)
{
    int suma;

    for(int i=0;i=A;i++)
    {
        a+=1;
        sleep(5);
        cout<<"El valor de a es:"<< a <<endl;
    }
    return data;
}

void *resta(void *data)
{
    int resta;

    for(int i=0;i=B;i++)
    {
        a-=1;
        sleep(5);
        cout<<"El valor de a es:"<< a <<endl;

    }
    return data;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_attr_t atributos;

    cout<<"Valor de A a sumar:"<<endl;
    cin>>A;
    cout<<"Valor de B a restar:"<<endl;
    cin>>B;
    pthread_t proceso1; //Identificador de los hilos
    pthread_t proceso2;

    int pthread_create(pthread_t* proceso1, const pthread_attr_t *_NULL,void *(*suma)(void *),void *&a);// Crea el hilo, pone parametros por defecto, le muestra su rutina y el valor con el que va a ejecutar la rutina
    int pthread_create(pthread_t* proceso2, const pthread_attr_t *_NULL,void *(*resta)(void *),void *&a);
    pthread_join(proceso1,NULL);
    pthread_join(proceso2,NULL);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hay otras preguntas con sobre ese error. Fíjate si alguna te ayuda. También puedes debugear el código y ver dónde surge. Esa información facilitaría ayudarte. Por cierto, qué quieres hacer con `pthread_create()`? Porque en ambas líneas tienes una declaración y parece que no haces nada con ello. Por otra parte, no es necesario que declares dos funciones iguales. Solo estás cambiando los nombres de algunos parámetros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se porque el compilador de c++ no se quejó por tu código.

### Problema 1:

El problema es que el compilador toma esta linea de código como prototipos de función(o eso creo):

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t* proceso1, const pthread_attr_t *_NULL,void *(*suma)(void *),void *&a);// Crea el hilo, pone parámetros por defecto, le muestra su rutina y el valor con el que va a ejecutar la rutina
int pthread_create(pthread_t* proceso2, const pthread_attr_t *_NULL,void *(*resta)(void *),void *&a);
```

Por lo que la función `pthread_create` nunca se realiza. Y cuando quieres liberar la memoria usada con `pthread_join` el compilador libera un hilo que no existe(recuerda que usar el valor de una variable sin inicializar trae valores impredecibles: `int a;cout

El otro problema que te saldrá después es con los bucles for: `for(int i=0;i=A;i++);`. lo que haces ahí es crear un bucle infinito, que siempre pone a `i` con el valor de `A` con cada iteración: `i=A//cambiar el valor de i a A`, `i==A//Compara el valor de i con A`. Y tampoco es el tipo de comparación que quieres, el que quieres es: `i

### Solución 1:

Debes colocar los valores como se debe al llamar la función:

```
//int pthread_create(pthread_t *th, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*func)(void *), void *arg);
pthread_create(&proceso1, NULL,suma,(void*)&a);
pthread_create(&proceso2, NULL,resta,(void*)&a);
```

### Consejo:

Como dijo @Mateo puedes usar la misma función para los dos hilos, solo debes aplicar esta formula: `+x+=a+=1, +x-=a+=-1;. Solo debes pasar el argumento que cambie el numero a que se va a sumar: a+=num_2;//en el hilo 1 se pasa 1, en el hilo 2 se pasa -1.` . También le debes pasar como argumento A o B para el bucle:

```
int list[2][2]={
        {
            A,
            1//+1+1: 2
        },
        {
            B,
            -1// recuerda que cuando se realiza esta suma: +2-1 es igual a 1. Porque +-==-. Esto nos permite usar la misma funcion para obtener los mismos resultados.
        }
    };
    //No pasamos "a" porque es una variable globa, y se puede acceder sin problema desde la función.
    pthread_create(&proceso1, NULL,suma,(void*)list[0]);// Crea el hilo, pone parámetros por defecto, le muestra su rutina y el valor con el que va a ejecutar la rutina
    pthread_create(&proceso2, NULL,suma,(void*)list[1]);
```

Y la función suma quedaría:

```
void* suma(void* data)
{
    const int COUNT=(int)((int*)data)[0];//Recuerda debemos convertir de void* a int* porque le necesitamos acceder a los elemento del array que pasamos(int*).
    const int NUM_2=(int)((int*)data)[1];
    for(int i=0;i<COUNT;i++)//repare.
    {
        a+=NUM_2;
        sleep(2);// 5 me parece muy lento cuando quiero ver los resultado rápido.
        cout<<"El valor de a es:"<< a <<endl;
    }
    return data;
}
```

### Codigo completo:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

int a=0;

void* suma(void* data)
{
    const int COUNT=(int)((int*)data)[0];//Recuerda debemos convertir de void* a int* porque le necesitamos acceder a los elemento del array que pasamos(int*).
    const int NUM_2=(int)((int*)data)[1];
    for(int i=0;i<COUNT;i++)//repare.
    {
        a+=NUM_2;
        sleep(2);
        cout<<"El valor de a es:"<< a <<endl;
    }
    return data;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_attr_t atributos;
    int A=0,B=0;
    cout<<"Valor de A a sumar:"<<endl;
    cin>>A;
    cout<<"Valor de B a restar:"<<endl;
    cin>>B;
    pthread_t proceso1; //Identificador de los hilos
    pthread_t proceso2;
    int list[2][2]={
        {
            A,
            1//+1+1: 2
        },
        {
            B,
            -1// recuerda que cuando se realiza esta suma: +2-1 es igual a 1. Porque +-==-. Esto nos permite usar la misma función para obtener los mismos resultados.
        }
    };
    pthread_create(&proceso1, NULL,suma,(void*)list[0]);// Crea el hilo, pone parametros por defecto, le muestra su rutina y el valor con el que va a ejecutar la rutina
    pthread_create(&proceso2, NULL,suma,(void*)list[1]);
    pthread_join(proceso1,NULL);
    pthread_join(proceso2,NULL);
    
    return 0;
}
```